# Replacing values in yml file using yq - invalid key reference

Tags: awk, sed, yaml, yq

I am currently working with editing/modifying yml files. I am a bit new using yq and unsure if I am going overboard using the tool. I am trying to replace two values in the yaml file with two environment values(linux system) as shown below. I am getting an invalid key reference error just simply trying to read the fields of that field using yq. What will be the best approach for modifying the fields the yml file? Would it be better to use sed or awk?

Environment Variables

```
$APP_KEY="DSDedfwerer02"
$APP_NAME="Test1"
```

test.yml

```
common: &default_settings
  app_key: ""
  app_name: ""
  some_key1: "test"
  some_key2: "onetwo"
  some_key3: "filename"
  another_key_n: "somevalue"
```

Desired result: test.yml

```
common: &default_settings
  app_key: "DSDedfwerer02"
  app_name: "Test1"
```

Comment: Can you provide `yq` command which you have tried to use and gave you *invalid key reference error*?

Comment: Which yq are you using mikefarah/yq (Go) or kisulyuk/yq (Python). See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info

Comment: @Inian I am using the mikefarah/yq (Go)

Comment: Are `APP_KEY` and `APP_NAME` really **environment variable**, i.e. they are exported and so available to subshells? Or did you just mean to say "variables" rather than "environment variables" and they aren't actually exported and so shouldn't really be all upper case (see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization))?

Comment: @EdMorton correct they are environment variables - available to subshells.

Comment: Just curious - why? Why do you need to export them?

Comment: @MaryCoding: Checkout my answer with yq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), it is relatively straightforward to just import the environment variables to the local context and update the required YAML elements

```
k="$APP_KEY" n="$APP_NAME" yq '.common |= ( . + {"app_key": strenv(k), "app_name": strenv(n)} ) | ..style="double"' yaml
```

Use the `-i` or `--inplace` flag to update the file inplace. Tested on version `v4.25.3`

Comment: Just seeing this now. This is great! So this shows an output, would it possible through yq making that modification and saving the file with those values?

Comment: Thanks! One thing I see that this removes all the other variables that the yml may contains. Would it possible to keep those other variables that could be in that file\?

Comment: Just updated that.

Comment: Awesome. I am testing it and I am seeing that it removes certain parts. For example `common: &default_settings` and changes it to `common`. Do you get that same behavior?

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't get a good `yq` answer, here's how to do what you're asking for in any awk given the sample input you provided:

```
$ APP_KEY="DSDedfwerer02"
$ APP_NAME="Test1"
$ awk -v key="$APP_KEY" -v name="$APP_NAME" '
    BEGIN { map["app_key:"]=key; map["app_name:"]=name }
    $1 in map { sub(/".*/,""); $0=$0 "\"" map[$1] "\"" }
1' file
common: &default_settings
  app_key: "DSDedfwerer02"
  app_name: "Test1"
```

That will work whether your shell variables really are environment variables or not and assuming they don't contain any backslashes and assuming `app_key:` and `app_name:` only appear as the first strings in the input in the positions you want their values replaced.

If they truly are environment variables then you can do:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { map["app_key:"]=ENVIRON["APP_KEY"]; map["app_name:"]=ENVIRON["APP_NAME"] }
    $1 in map { sub(/".*/,""); $0=$0 "\"" map[$1] "\"" }
1' file
```

or if not:

```
APP_KEY="$APP_KEY" APP_NAME="$APP_NAME" \
awk '
    BEGIN { map["app_key:"]=ENVIRON["APP_KEY"]; map["app_name:"]=ENVIRON["APP_NAME"] }
    $1 in map { sub(/".*/,""); $0=$0 "\"" map[$1] "\"" }
1' file
```

which will work even if they contain backslashes.

Comment: This it! awk is the much simpler approach.

Comment: I havent test it yet, but will this be affected if they are strings that follow bellow `app_key` and `app_name`?

Comment: Only if they're also named `app_key:` and `app_name:` and also occur as the first strings tin a line.

Comment: Ok perfect, these key values are unique so that answers that.

Comment: Another consultation, if the keys already contain a value such as `app_key:"test"` this tends to append to it like this `app_key:"test""new value"`. Is there a way to replace if a value is present?

Comment: Sure but that's why you use a tool that understands the language the file is written in as opposed to trying to parse text based on provided example(s). Please ask a new question and this time really think about the various ways your input might be formatted other than what you've shown so far so we can best help you. Though it'd be easy, I don't want to solve this new problem only to then have another problem, then another - just show us everything at once in a new question.